# Android unchecking radio buttons

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have this 3 Radio buttons, let's assume radio1, radio2, radio3. What i did is if i checked radio1 and radio2, the radio3 will be uncheckable and so on. So i can only check 2 buttons at a time.

Then i made this button that if i clicked it, it will unchecked all the checked radio buttons. Now what my problem is whenever i try to check radio1 and radio2 and clear it. The radio3 still won't be clickable even if the radio1 and 2 aren't checked anymore.

```
RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
RadioButton radio3;
Button clear;
TextView tv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondxml);
radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd1);
radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd2);
radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd3);
radio1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
radio2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
radio3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    radio1.setChecked(false);
    radio2.setChecked(false);
    radio3.setChecked(false);
    tv.setText("");
    }
});
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(radio1.isChecked() && radio2.isChecked()){
        tv.setText("Radio1 and 2 is checked ");
        radio3.setClickable(false);
    }
    if(radio1.isChecked() && radio3.isChecked()){
            radio2.setClickable(false);
        tv.setText("radio 1 and 3 is checked");

    }
    if(radio2.isChecked() && radio3.isChecked()){
        radio1.setClickable(false);
        tv.setText("radio2 and 3 is checked");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You have therefore set `radio3` to not be clickable by calling `radio3.setClickable(false);` when you selected `radio1` and `radio2`. Your clear button doesn't reverse this.

I suggest in your `onClick(...)` method for your clear `OnClickListener` you call

```
radio1.setClickable(true);
radio2.setClickable(true);
radio3.setClickable(true);
```

this would stop them being disabled when you clear the selection, bringing them back to the default state.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when using an individual radio button as opposed to radio group the key is using radio.isSelected() to find the current state of the button.

This code to my on touch listener fixed a similar problem I was having:

```
     OnClickListener radio_button_click = (new OnClickListener() {  

 public void onClick(View v) {  
                  RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;   

                  if( rb.isSelected()==true) {
                      rb.setSelected(false);
                      rb.setChecked(false);
                      rb.setClickable(true);

                  }
                  else{
                      rb.setSelected(true);
                  rb.setClickable(true);

                  }
}

}
```